# Join multiple table performance

Tags: sql-server, left-join, large-data

In my current project, I have to left join multiple table (about 10->20 table) together. In these tables, there are about 1->3 large table with millions row (at maximum: 80 millions), the other table only have thousands row at most.

Currently, my query is like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 left join table2 on table1.A=table2.A
table1 left join table3 on table1.B=table3.B
table1 left join table4 on table1.C=table4.C
table1 left join table5 on table1.D=table5.D
....
table1 left join table15 on table1.Z=table15.Z
```

table1 and table2 are large table, other are small. 
I have clustered index in all of these table but the performance is still low. So, I want to know if there is anything I can try to increase the performance.

p/s: I have try to create nonclustered index in these table but the performance become lower than before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql query joins multiple tables - too slow (8 tables)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806015/sql-query-joins-multiple-tables-too-slow-8-tables). [First answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1002612/69809) suggests that correlated queries might work faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well the fastest query would be if you de-normalized your table1 so that the split out normalized values were actually part of the table.

Another solution that you might try is building a temp table that was one big collection of the 20 other small tables.  And then just join that temp table back to your table1.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, do you really need all those joined data? I suppose most of the situations you don't. If you do, you probably need to review your requirements and architecture.

So the trick is, you only get the data you want, instead of all of them. And filter the data as early as possible (even before joining the next table. but don't worry, SQL Server would do some optimization for you).

I would start from checking the execution plan with Ctrl+L. Try finding out those "Index Scan" nodes and build index for them. I can't go any further without seeing your execution plan.