# MySQL select several columns of several tables at the same time without using JOIN

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT id, 
(SELECT payer_id FROM transactions WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT sentence FROM cofg_sentences WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT name FROM cofg_options WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT hour FROM cofg_time WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT field_id, url FROM cofg_feeds WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT field_id, fb_user FROM cofg_accounts WHERE id = user_id) 
FROM users WHERE token = '.......'
```

I am trying to do this query but I am receiving this error:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

If I delete second column of subquery I get:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I know there are other question with the same error but the queries are different. I don't want to use JOIN because I have read it will decrease the perfomance.

What are the problems here? Any kind of help is appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell us who said that a `JOIN` will decrease performances, so that we can throw stones at him. Doing `JOIN` is the essence of a RDBMS.

Comment: @RandomSeed I have read post like this: stackoverflow.com/a/1002612/2528167
saying there are several cases subqueries are better, for example when you have to join many tables like me, but I am seeing I would have to use JOIN to complete my purpose. Thank you

Comment: Okay in some cases, transforming a JOIN into a subquery may *improve* performance, but this is a very borderline case in my opinion (12 tables joined? all you need to do sometimes is slightly increase some buffers). Besides, you are looking at a 4 year old post; things may have changed since then. Anyways, this is a perfect example of premature optimisation. Go with JOIN in general, only tweak queries that have a real performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to use JOIN because I have read it will decrease the perfomance`

What did you find when you measured it?

The pattern of putting sub queries in the select clause is a viable technique for fixing some performance problems **if you know what the optimiser is doing and what your data looks like**.

You should start by implementing your code using proper joins then change it if it needs to be changed.

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Is caused by

```
(SELECT field_id, url FROM
```

If it is appropriate to use a sub query you can avoid this error by concatenating the values with a separator then splitting them later.

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Should be self evident and is solved by aggregating the rows or limiting to one row.

Comment: I have read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1002612/2528167
According to you, could I return efficiently several columns with several rows of several tables using INNER JOIN? Thank you

Comment: It depends of the length of your table and how indexed is your database. Subqueries performance are usually worse than JOINS but it depends how your database is well modeled. I think is a good idea run both ways and compare the results.

Comment: I am developing the project, I still can't compare results. I have one table for each type of data and all have user_id column to relate them. I am using unique index for columns but nothing else. Is neccesary an index for JOINS? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you agree the tipical SQL row is something like:

```
   SQL Row Example:
   COLUMN1    COLUMN2    COLUMN3    COLUMN4
   1          anyvalue   2          othervalue
```

When you run a subquery it should return a simple VALUE with 1 row and 1 column so you still having a tipical SQL row.

```
   SQL Row Example:
   COLUMN1    COLUMN2      COLUMN3    COLUMN4
   SUBQUERY   anyvalue     2          othervalue
```

Lets go. Fist error:

> ## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

you are trying to put 2 columns in a place supposed to have one simple value.

Second error:

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

your SQL is returning many rows with many values but it is expecting only one simple value as I said before.

Adding a TOP to limit the row numbers would be a solution in your case:

```
SELECT id, 
(SELECT TOP 1 payer_id FROM transactions WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT TOP 1 sentence FROM cofg_sentences WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT TOP 1 name FROM cofg_options WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT TOP 1 hour FROM cofg_time WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT TOP 1 url FROM cofg_feeds WHERE id = user_id), 
(SELECT TOP 1 fb_user FROM cofg_accounts WHERE id = user_id) 
FROM users WHERE token = '.......'
```

I don't want to interfere in your logic. I will just explain something about subquery:

You have 6 subqueries in your SELECT. It means you will hit the database six times for each user.
If you have 100 users you will hit your database 600 times just in one simple SQL instruction.

Think about use joins!

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Do you think I could return efficiently several columns with several rows of several tables using INNER JOIN?