# How to increase speed of stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this stored procedure which shows almost 70,000 records but it takes considerable time to run, i.e. **1 min 4 secs**

How to boost it's performance?

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN c.CardID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.CardID END AS CardID,
    CASE WHEN c.Description IS NULL THEN '' ELSE c.Description END AS Description,
    CASE WHEN c.Employee_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Employee_ID END AS Employee_ID,
    CASE WHEN c.ExpiryDate IS NULL THEN '1900-01-01' ELSE DATEADD(HOUR,4,c.ExpiryDate) END AS ExpiryDate,
    CASE WHEN c.IsActive IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE c.IsActive END AS IsActive,
    CASE WHEN c.IssueDate IS NULL THEN '1900-01-01' ELSE DATEADD(HOUR,4,c.IssueDate) END AS 'IssueDate',
    CASE WHEN c.PinCode IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.PinCode END AS PinCode,
    e.EmployeeUniqueID, e.EmployeeName,
    ER.EmployerName,
    CASE WHEN c.IsActive = '1' THEN 'Activate' ELSE 'Deactivate' END AS Status   
FROM
    Cards c  
RIGHT JOIN
    RegisteredEmployees e ON c.Employee_ID = e.ID  
INNER JOIN 
    POSSystem.DBO.Employers ER ON E.Employer_ID = ER.ID
```

Comment: Please read how to ask a good sql question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056
Also you should post the explain plan

Comment: use a correlated subqueries instead of joins check this one out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806015/sql-query-joins-multiple-tables-too-slow-8-tables

Comment: questions seeking peformance help need to include ,table schema,count of tables involved and current execution plan

Comment: Right join... Most people find left join hard enough to understand. Do yourself and everybody else, switch to left join! (It's much easier to understand "main table left join optional data" than "optional data right join main table".)

Comment: @Dark, correlated subqueries tend to be very slow in SQL server. Joins are preferred.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use an Explain plan, the OP should post the Execution plan.

Comment: Indexing is the most likely cause of the problem. What indexes do you have on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you index the tables that you are hitting.

See the link below for all details.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/14-sql-server-indexing-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

Answer (score -3):

You can use parallel execution of sqls.

Like,

```
SELECT /*+ Parallel(s,8) */ 
       Case When c.CardID IS NULL then 0 else c.CardID end CardID  
      ,Case When c.Description IS NULL then '' else c.Description end Description  
      ,CASE when c.Employee_ID IS NULL then 0 else Employee_ID end Employee_ID 
      ,CASE when c.ExpiryDate IS NULL then '1900-01-01' else DATEADD(HOUR,4,c.ExpiryDate) end as ExpiryDate
      ,Case when c.IsActive IS NULL then '0' else c.IsActive end as IsActive  
      ,CASE when c.IssueDate IS NULL then '1900-01-01' else DATEADD(HOUR,4,c.IssueDate) end as 'IssueDate'
      ,CASE When c.PinCode IS NULL then 0 else c.PinCode end as PinCode  
      ,e.EmployeeUniqueID
      ,e.EmployeeName  
      ,ER.EmployerName
      ,case when c.IsActive='1' then 'Activate' else 'Deactivate' end as Status   
    from Cards c  
    right join RegisteredEmployees e  
    on c.Employee_ID=e.ID  
    INNER JOIN POSSystem.DBO.Employers ER
    ON E.Employer_ID=ER.ID
```

Reference : [Click Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c20paral.htm)

Hope it will help.

Comment: The post is tagged as Sql-Server. That hinting technique is for Oracle DB