# SQL Server view running slowly

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Before you read this, I have to mention that my question is different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806015/sql-query-joins-multiple-tables-too-slow-8-tables). Please don't consider it as similar question.
I have a view in SQL Server like this:

```
Select 
    field1, field2 , ... (About 150 columns)
From 
    Orders O
Inner Join 
    Customers C on C.sustomerID = O.CustomerId 
Inner Join 
    ... (about 20 more inner joins & left joins)
```

Then my web page calls this big query (sp) and takes about 1 minutes to return the data.

- All tables are indexes carefully
- All foreign keys and relations set properly

but it runs slowly. I've tried to convert it to an "Indexed View" based on this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) but it does not work because of limitation of using left joins in indexed views.

Any solution to have a faster view?

Comment: Try making multiple smaller `indexed views` and then use those views to create the final resultset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql query joins multiple tables - too slow (8 tables)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806015/sql-query-joins-multiple-tables-too-slow-8-tables)

Comment: @Raj  That does not work because of the complexity of the query.

Comment: Does it take 1 minute to run in SSMS? In your web page do you select all data or do you filter on it? Are there any suggestions when you check the query plan? How up to date does this data need to be?

Comment: @Koby that is totally different issue

Comment: @Nick Yes, it even takes more than 1 minutes. A couple of the tables are really big (millions of records) with more than 50 columns. And I have to do the query as we have something like a dashboard shows all the results.

Comment: @Koby Why you downgrade the question without reading my comment?

Comment: @MortezaMadadi I did not downvote your question.

Comment: @KobyDouek sorry but it mentioned same link as you did

Comment: Since it takes the same time in SSMS as the web portal we know that it needs to be adressed in the database. If you feel you have done all the optimisation you can (indexes, partitioning, FK's, query plan) then the next thing I would suggest is to regularly load the view into a table and run your report out of the table. It depends how up to date your data needs to be though.

Comment: Did you try to use stored procedure instead of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem. Tried all the solutions mentioned above with no result. Finally I decided to make a new de-normalized table including all columns needed for the query and saved it (the new table includes all columns I needed in the view). Then inserted all result from stored procedure to the new table (insert into new table from view result). Then added a couple of triggers to track insert-update-delete changes to the new table. It is working now for about 6 months with no issue so far.

Also added a new indexes to the new table so it get fast enough.

Comment: Thanks @Amir978, I have created a new table including all fields I need. Is there any other way to track the changes in the join tables rather than trigger?

Comment: That's the only solution I know

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE VIEW` It is still working not to fast, but could help in not too large tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could 'materialise' this view by selecting it into a staging table on a regular basis (ever x minutes via a schedule) and selecting directly from that table in your app.

I'd question how useful 150 columns is to an end user. With that sort of data size, you're transferring a lot of data to the client which will always be slow (for transmission and probably display in the browser). I doubt any user will find 150 columns of data useful.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is frequent for many people so you can use the MATERIALIZED views, this will help you fast execution. You can take help from the below mentioned link from oracle.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm

Or you can use /**+MATERIALIZED*/ hint while selecting the data from views.

as select /**+MATERIALIZED*/ * from table1

Comment: materialized view in MS SQL has so many limitations and one of them is: You can't use left join. If you click on the link I provided, you can see the article. so it is different to Oracle

Comment: Agree.. So what is your suggestion for improvement

Comment: I think @Amir153 provided the best answer so far. (I selected it as answer)