# Joins and linked servers query causing delay

Tags: sql-server

Hey guys the code below is taking a really long time. I've been looking at it for quite a while. Is there anything that stands out as the obvious cause of delay?

[SQLSRV-3-JB] is a linked server BTW

```
Select count(cast (Unique_ID as bigint)) as [Count],
       T.[Region_Code],
       T.[Region_Name],
       U.[Region_Code],
       Y.[Examination_Year], 
       case when [Subject] = 'MUSIC THEORY' THEN 'Theory' 
            else 'Practical' 
       end  
from   [SQLSRV-3-JB].[X].[dbo].[Exam_and_Candidate_Details] Y
  left join [SQLSRV-3-JB].[X].[dbo].[UK_Exam_Centre_Info] T 
    on Y.Centre_Code = T.Centre_Code
  left join [SQLSRV-3-JB].[X].[dbo].[UK_Exam_Centres] U 
    on Y.Centre_Code = U.Centre_Code
where  Y.[Examination_Year] between 2010 and 2016 
group by Y.[Examination_Year],
         T.[Region_Code],
         T.[Region_Name],
         U.[Region_Code],
         case when [Subject] = 'MUSIC THEORY' THEN 'Theory' 
              else 'Practical' 
         end
```

Comment: The only thing anybody would be able to tell without table and index definitions would be nonSARGable predicates. Don't see any of those here. That means if you want some help we need to have the definitions and probably an actual execution plan. Sometimes this type of query can be sped up by creating a view or procedure on the remote server to minimize the amount of data being sent back.

Comment: Without any knowledge of the size of the tables being queried, it makes it difficult to identify if there are 'obvious' reasons for delay. There are some similar questions which suggest the use of [correlated subqueries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806015/sql-query-joins-multiple-tables-too-slow-8-tables), using [indexes](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/) and another thing you may want to consider is the ordering of your joins i.e. is it possible to subset the data more before joining larger tables? Good luck!

Comment: Thank you both for your input. Much appreciated. I have found a solution using the view method detailed by @LaughingVergil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is one very obvious problem - the remote server. When you use a linked server like this, SQL Server has a disturbing habit of pulling all of the data in the remote tables to the local server **before** performing JOINs or filtration.

The correct way to handle this is to make this query a view on the remote server, and query the view with your WHERE clause on your end. So, your remote code would look like this:

```
-- Remote Server
USE X
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.ExamCenterInfo 
AS
    Select count(cast (Unique_ID as bigint)) as [Count],
           T.[Region_Code],
           T.[Region_Name],
           U.[Region_Code],
           Y.[Examination_Year], 
           case when [Subject] = 'MUSIC THEORY' THEN 'Theory' 
                else 'Practical' 
           end  
    from dbo.[Exam_and_Candidate_Details] Y
    left join dbo.[UK_Exam_Centre_Info] T 
        on Y.Centre_Code = T.Centre_Code
    left join dbo.[UK_Exam_Centres] U 
        on Y.Centre_Code = U.Centre_Code
    group by Y.[Examination_Year],
             T.[Region_Code],
             T.[Region_Name],
             U.[Region_Code],
             case when [Subject] = 'MUSIC THEORY' THEN 'Theory' 
                  else 'Practical' 
             end
```

Then your local code:

```
-- Local Server

SELECT *
FROM   [SQLSRV-3-JB].[X].[dbo].ExamCenterInfo ECI
    where ECI.[Examination_Year] between 2010 and 2016
```

NOTE: There is some possibility that this will pull all of the view output before filtering by year. If this is still a problem, you will have to create a more complex mechanism to execute the view with filtration on the remote server.